# use a 2-way-2-gang switch to control a dual-speed fan motor

Tags: switch, motor

[image]I want to use a 2-way-2-gang switch to control a dual-speed fan motor. The switch has six poles on the back: L11, L1, L12, L21, L2 & L22. The motor has two terminals: High Speed and Low Speed. The idea: switch L1 is for overall On and Off and switch L2 is for selection of two speeds.

My connection looks like this:

External L line -> L1
L11 -> L2
L21 -> High Speed terminal of the motor
L22 -> Low Speed terminal of the motor

Is it so far correct? Do I miss something?

Comment: Model #? Link to installation manual?